# How to Deploy Java Project using SVN in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

i'm new to the Using SVN tool,

How to Deploy java Project Using SVN in Eclipse IDE.

Please explain any one step by step process in SVN tool in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Do you already have an SVN repo that you can clone from?

Comment: Is this a new project or are you checking out an existing project?

Comment: SVN will get whatever is server sided, if there you have an eclipse project then you can import it, otherwise you will have to create your own project and add there the src code, you can move the whole project to the svn and commit it so you can have the setup already there.

Comment: I would recommend reading http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html to get an understanding of what svn is and how it works

Comment: Yes i'm develop sample application using java and now i want to deploy project using svn!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add an SVN plugin to your eclipse and follow the instructions as given

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/